# Django REST Framework: Generics or ModelViewSets?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I use generics and plain urls for my REST API, but now I stuck with problem: I want custom actions, simple views to make some things with my models, like "run", "publish", etc.

`ViewSet` gives `action` decorator to create custom actions, but only in ViewSets, also, there is stepial routers, which gives us ability to simplify everything using railsish convention-over-configuration.

But I find that `ModelViewSet` gives us same abilities, as generics: full CRUD, serializers, filters, cusstom pre/post and queryset, so, it leads to question:

Why there is generics if `ModelViewSet` gives same abilities and more? What a difference?

Answer (score 20):

The difference is what methods they offer.

For example:

**GenericViewSet** inherits from GenericAPIView but does not provide any implementations of basic actions. Just only get_object, get_queryset.

**ModelViewSet**  inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions. In other words you dont need implement basic actions as list, retrieve, create, update or destroy. Of course you can override them and implement your own list or your own create methods.

You can read more about it, in the API REFERENCE section:
 [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets)

Comment: I want to know difference between ModelViewSet and generic like ListCreateAPIView

Comment: You are asking what is the difference between ModelViewSet and Generics ?

Comment: That's what I said :)

Comment: I edited my answer,check it please, but the difference is similar.

Comment: If you use only GenericViewSet you need to implement your own create, destroy, etc, instead of if you use ModelViewSet, that has already a create, destroy, list, etc methods.

Comment: Argh… look, there is generics like ListCreatrAPIView, which implements list and create methods. But DRF has similar thing - ModelViewSet, which implements it too! So, both generics and ModelViewSet implements methods. So, what is the difference?

Comment: That, ModelViewSet implements more methods than GenericViewSet. 
ModelViewSet has: .list(), .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), and .destroy(). GenericViewSet: does not has these methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58643/discussion-between-levi-and-dt0xff).

Comment: Okay, look, DRF has module generics.py,  which provides APIView classes with mixins, so it has all methods implemented. Okay, next. DRF has module  viewsets.py, which has ViewSet classes with mixins, so it has same implementation of CRUD methods! But provides exactly same api: serializers, filters, permissions, BUT also provides ability to use it in DRF Router with custom views(actions). The question is: what is the real difference so we still have generics.py?

Comment: But generics.py does not have the same implemented methods than viewsets.py . You can read it on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets look at API REFERENCE

Comment: Nope. These methods are implemented in mixins.py classes, which is inherited in both generics APIView and ModelViewSet

Comment: They say "but does not include any actions by default." reffering about GenericViews. Try to use them and you see you cant.

Answer (score 10):

The difference between **Generics** or **ModelViewSet** is that:

1. Convenient
   Usually **ModelViewSet** is more convenient. Because **ModelViewSet** support creating url pattern automatically with DRF router. But **Generics** don't. you do yourself.
2. Shorten and crispy code
   If you want to create CRUD, **Generics** needs two classes(ListCreateAPIView and RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView). But **ModelViewSet** needs only one class(ModelViewSet).

Check out Declaration below. Both inherits from *GenericAPIView* and *mixins.CreateModelMixin*, *mixins.ListModelMixin* It provides equivalent functionality basically. It depends on what you prefer. But I usually use ViewSet in most cases.

---

**Declaration**

```
# Generics __________________________________
class ListCreateAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        mixins.CreateModelMixin, 
                        GenericAPIView):

# ModelViewSet _____________________________
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet):

# GenericViewSet _____________________________
class GenericViewSet(ViewSetMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
```

**Example code**

```
# Generics __________________________________
from rest_framework import generics

class BookList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

# ModelViewSet _____________________________
from rest_framework import viewsets

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

Comment: If ModelViewset provides options for basic CRUD operations, why are we inheriting different mixin classes while declaring a ModelViewset?

Answer (score 8):

> Why there is generics if ModelViewSet gives same abilities and more?

Let me first rephrase the question a little more explicitly for you...

"Why are there Generic Views, when there are also Generic ViewSets"

Which really just comes down to a question of why REST framework supports both views and viewsets. Answer - ViewSets are useful for prototyping or for cases when your API URLs neatly map to a fixed convention throughout (eg CRUD style APIs). Views are useful for being explicit, or for cases when your URLs do not neatly map to a fixed convention throughout.

Comment: But `GenericAPIView`s are bound to similar logic too, I mean, you have `ListCreateAPIView`(with Create and List mixins), which should be assigned to one url, so it has some convention. But you can do same with `ViewSet`, just by inheriting only Create and List mixins. But, with APIView you are forced to use post to create and get to list. With ViewSet you can bind different actions to different requests with argument to `to_view` method. So, ViewSet looks more agile... But yea, there is `router`, which makes "convention" and works only with `ViewSets`. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Oh, well, source answers all questions: ModelViewSet inherits GenericAPIView. So, GenericAPIView classes provides ability to override post/get/put/delete request views. It uses mixins and assigns `post` to `create`, `get` to `list`, etc. The problem is: for example, `list` and `retrieve` uses `get`, so we can't mix it in `GenericAPIView`. But, there is `ViewSet`, which gives ability to override `actions`, not http request type(POST, GET, PUT) views. This is, as I see, the main ideological difference, is it?

Answer (score 0):

ModelViewSet works with router so you don't have to map the URLs youself. While with GenericAPIView, you have to define individual URLs for every http method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).