# generics vs viewset in django rest framework, how to prefer which one to use?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to prefer which one of generics and viewset to use?
in other words when should I use generics and when should I use viewset for building api.
I know that they do the same thing, but viewset has routers, so in what situation generics are better than viewset?

Comment: You could start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125959/django-rest-framework-generics-or-modelviewsets)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

They are different, let's see.

DRF has two main systems for handling views:

1. [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/): This provides methods handler for **http verbs**: `get`, `post`, `put`, `patch`, and `delete`.
2. [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets): This is an abstraction over APIView, which provides **actions** as methods:

   - `list`: read only, returns multiple resources (http verb: `get`). Returns a list of dicts.
   - `retrieve`: read only, single resource (http verb: `get`, but will expect an id in the url). Returns a single dict.
   - `create`: creates a new resource (http verb: `post`)
   - `update/partial_update`: edits a resource (http verbs: `put/patch`)
   - `destroy`: removes a resource (http verb: `delete`)

Both can be used with normal django urls.

Because of the conventions established with the **actions**, the `ViewSet` has also the ability to be [mapped into a router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter), which is really helpful.

Now, both of this Views, have **shortcuts**, these shortcuts give you a simple implementation ready to be used.

[GenericAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview): for `APIView`, this gives you shortcuts that map closely to your database models. Adds commonly required behavior for standard list and detail views. Gives you some attributes like, the `serializer_class`, also gives `pagination_class`, `filter_backend`, etc

[GenericViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset): There are many GenericViewSet, the most common being `ModelViewSet`. They inherit from `GenericAPIView` and have a full implementation of all of the **actions**: `list`, `retrieve`, `destroy`, `updated`, etc. Of course, you can also pick some of them, [read the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example_3).

So, to answer your question: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), if you are doing something really simple, with a `ModelViewSet` should be enough, even redefining and calling `super` also is enough. For more complex cases, you can go for lower level classes.

Hope to have helped you!

Comment: Is it a best practice to mix them, and why ?

Comment: There's no best practice here. I'd say: try to keep it simple, use `ModelViewSet`, but sometimes you need the flexibility, so it's fine to use a `ViewSet` or an `APIView`. But in the end, is up to you, is not wrong to use `APIView` for everything if you want,

Comment: I found one more nice answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879333/8454203

Answer (score 17):

My golden rule for this is to use generics whenever I have to override the default methods to accomplish different specifications from list and details views.

For instance, when you have different serializer classes for listing your resources and for retrieving a resource details by id I consider that using generics is a better option since probably these two endpoints' logic is going to evolve separately. Keep in mind is a good practice to maintain different logics decoupled.

When your endpoint is very simple and you don't need to customize logic between list/create and retrieve/update/delete operations you can use viewset, but yet having in mind it may be good to separate it in two views in case these operations' logic start growing in different paths.

Comment: Is it a best practice to mix them and why?