# Change model field if requested particular url

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-polymorphic

Im making API using django rest framework . I only want to change one field in model which is the read field if i go to a particular url

my model:

```
class Notification(PolymorphicModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(ElsUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, related_name="creatednotifications")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_for = models.ForeignKey(ElsUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, related_name="receivednotifications")
    read = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, max_length=800)
```

The APis i made lists the notifications for a logged in user.

What i want to implement is that :

```
notification/<:id>/markread

notification/<:id>/markunread
```

If i go to this particular url i want to modify the read field ..For example make it None if to mark unread. Also i need to check if the logged in user has received the notification with that id.I know the basics and how to create the urls

```
class NotificationMarkRead(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset =  Notification.objects.filter(created_for=self.request.user)

        return queryset 

class NotificationMarkUnread(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset =  Notification.objects.filter(created_for=self.request.user)

        return queryset 

    def update
```

My initial try is to override the put method in update_API view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple function:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def notification_toggle_read_status(request, pk, read_status):
    notification = Notification.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if read_status == 'markread':
        notification.read = timezone.now()
    else:
        notification.read = None
    notification.save(update_fields=['read'])
    serializer = NotificationSerializer(instance=notification)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

use this url path:

`notifications/<int:pk>/<string:read_status>/`

Comment: i used the same url as notifications/id for put method... Made All fields other that read as read_only fields

Answer (score 0):

As you have already coding with `DRF` why not try with `viewset` [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) . And from front-end just pass update fields with put request.

Comment: what  is the advantage of using viewsets instead of generic Views?

Comment: better you should go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125959/django-rest-framework-generics-or-modelviewsets)